# htaccess don't redirect root folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a htaccess rule that is fixing some of my previous URL change mistakes which looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^images.lazygamer\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-content|wp-admin|wp-includes|fixed|contact-details|advertise|about|category|submission|images|ps3|xbox-360|wii).*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.lazygamer.net/fixed/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So now if you have go to www.lazygamer.net/story/ it will redirect you to www.lazygamer.net/fixed/story which is perfect

BUT... it is also redirecting www.lazygamer.net to www.lazygamer.net/fixed ... how do I stop it doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "\/" to the URLs not be considered; something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(\/!wp-content|w...
```

Comment: no that didn't make any difference, now if I browse to the root it adds fixed/ to the end of the URL

Comment: Thanks to Claudio's help I managed to get to the answer, all I needed to do was add another condition as follows

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/$

The reason Claudio's answer didn't work was because it was only checking for after a trailing /